# hAxis.maxValue google charts

Tags: php, google-visualization

i am having Problems with Google Scatter Chart. The data contains user and their ratings for specific pictures. On the hAxis i have the users listed, on vAxis their rating.
I create 15 different Scatter Charts, for half of them the hAxis is working, for some it will display +5 or +3 (e.g. 20 instead of 15) - Number of users and Scatter Charts just coincidence right now. Sometimes it starts at 0, sometimes at 1. Here you can see the output code in the Browser:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['User', 'Rating'],          
      [ 1,      5],
      [ 2,      3],
      [ 3,      3],
      [ 4,      5],
      [ 5,      2],
      [ 6,      1],
      [ 7,      4],
      [ 8,      4],
      [ 9,      1],
      [ 10,      1],
      [ 11,      10],
      [ 12,      2],
      [ 13,      5],
      [ 14,      4],
      [ 15,      3],

    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'User and their ratings - Picture 6 (15 Ratings)',
      hAxis: {title: 'User', minValue: 1, maxValue: 15}, 
      vAxis: {title: 'Rating', minValue: 1, maxValue: 10},
      legend: 'none'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

This is my php Script:

```
 $query = "SELECT rate FROM rating WHERE bild = '$bild_i' ";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

 $menge = mysql_num_rows($result);

 echo'<html>
 <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
     function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      [\'User\', \'Rating\'],';

      $i = 1;

       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

 echo'          
         [ '.$i.',      '.$row['rate'].'],
 ';         $i++;
         }
  echo'       
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: \'User and their ratings - Picture '.$bild_i.' ('.$menge.' Ratings)\',
      hAxis: {title: \'User\', minValue: 1, maxValue: '.$menge.'}, 
      vAxis: {title: \'Rating\', minValue: 1, maxValue: 10},
      legend: \'none\'
    };
```

I have already tried some suggestions with the hAxis.viewWindowMode command, but it will display the same. Btw. the ('.$menge.' Ratings) always displays the correct number of user.  Can somebody help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that hAxis to span a specific range, then you need to use the `hAxis.viewWindow.min/max` options:

```
hAxis: {
    viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: 20
    }
}
```